# Java Play! Framework Development

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0

I have started with web development 2 months ago with python/gae. We switched from gae to amazon AWS and Java Play!.

1. Will I run into problems if I want to deploy my app on AWS? At the moment I can use Elasticbeanstalk and it's a oneclick solution. Is Elasticbeanstalk compatible with Play! ?
2. I don't know Scala. Because of the well written tutorial I have no problems using Scala for the templating / routing system. But maybe I will run into future problems. Would you recommend me to learn Scala if I want to use Play! ?
3. I can run my app locally without deploying it, which gives me a really good workflow. Would it be possible to develop for AWS and testing my app locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your questions

1. Since AWS Elastic Bean Stalk supports deployment of Java Web Apps on it.There wont be any problem deploying your Play! project.
2. You dont have to be a Scala Pro to use Play!.You'll get used to Scala while using Play! and eventually become proficient in it and then if you want you can learn it.
3. Of course you can develop your Application for AWS and test it locally.Eclipse IDE has a great plugin for that.

   http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/

Comment: AWS Elastic Bean Stalk contains a Servlet container (Tomcat) and you need to provide a WAR. Play application won't work on it. Play is not built on J2EE stack. Think about it as a Java application with built-in (netty) HTTP server. What you need to do is to run simple java application and put it behind load balancer. You can put your app into single zip using `play dist` command, upload it to AWS, unzip and run using `start` shell script provided.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Play! are you enquiring about?

Beanstalk hosts Tomcat and expects a servlet technology (servlets, filters, bundled as a WAR), whereas Play! 2.0 Scala edition results in a runnable Netty-based (non-servlet) program which binds to a port of your choosing. Play! 2.1 will support servlet 3.0. [See this ticket for milestone information.](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8)

So, you may want to monitor the progress of Play's servlet support, or Beanstalk's support for Netty-based technologies.

Comment: I am using Play! 2.0.3RC. Would something like this work? https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

Comment: Should do. The author himself commented on the link I posted: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8#ticket-8-7

Comment: From the Github page for that plugin, the support for Play! goes up to 2.0.2, so it's up to you to check if 2.0.3RC will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to upgrade to Play 2.3.x or newer, [Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) has native Play 2 support to address this.

Boxfuse creates a minimal image for you Play app that runs unchanged on VirtualBox and AWS.

You can write your app either in Java or Scala, but coming from Typesafe Play 2 has a strong bias for the latter.

To deploy to AWS with Boxfuse you can now simply execute `boxfuse run my-play-app-1.0.zip -env=prod` and this will automatically:

- create a minimal AMI tailor-made for your Play 2 app
- create an elastic IP
- create a security group with the correct permissions
- launch an instance of your app

All future updates are performed as **blue/green deployments with zero downtime**.

This also works with Elastic Load Balancers and Auto-Scaling Groups and the Boxfuse free tier is designed to fit the AWS free tier.

You can read more about it here: https://boxfuse.com/blog/playframework-aws

*Disclaimer: I'm the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*